# merge two arrays with a separator, javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to merge two arrays and have a separator included between all values (comma).  I tried this:

```
var aAndBWithCommasInBetween = a.concat(b);
```

But that leads to:

```
DealerOrigin
```

instead of:

```
Dealer, Origin
```

each a and b can have many values or none.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript-and-de-duplicate-items

Comment: Can you include example of arrays at Question ?

Comment: Are you merging arrays or strings?

Comment: It was merging two arrays of strings.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript-and-de-duplicate-items/36146642#36146642

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your a and b in the example are not arrays but strings, which is why concat creates another string.

```
['Apple'].concat(['Orange'])
["Apple", "Orange"]
```

versus

```
"Apple".concat("Orange")
"AppleOrange"
```

You could be looking for array.join(), which converts an array into a single string separated by commas or whatever separator you pass in.

```
["Apple", "Orange"].join(',')
"Apple,Orange"
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript-and-de-duplicate-items/36146642#36146642

Answer (score 2):

```
a=[1,2]
  [1, 2]
b=[3,5]
  [3, 5]
a.concat(b)
[1, 2, 3, 5]
```

It works fine. This is what I tried in the console.

If you try`a+b`,then You will get

```
 1,23,5
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript-and-de-duplicate-items/36146642#36146642

Answer (score 1):

```
var aAndBWithCommasInBetween = a.concat(b).join(',');
```